# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 39 in /my/path/*.phpFile on line 23

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, and trying to follow an online tutorial for making an android music player.  This PHP will connect to my DB, scan the directory for *.mp3 files, and add them to the DB. Anyway, I'm stuck at the final part, I connect, scan the files, see an output on my screen, and then get this error when trying to populate the database.  I've read a lot about an array issue causing the error, but I don't know how to troubleshoot any further.  FYI the DB column Id, is the primary key, set to auto inc.  Thank you for the help!  Here is the code:
    Makes connection to DB/

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "MusicApp2");

/*Test connection*/
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/*Scan directory for files*/
$files = glob('*.mp3');

usort ($files, function ($a, $b) {
    return filemtime ($a) <filemtime ($b);
});


/*Insert list of files to DB IF they don't exist*/
$i = 0;

while ($files[$i]) {
    $trackname = basename($files[$i]);
    echo $trackname."**";
    $addquery = "INSERT INTO music (Id, trackname, numlikes, numplays) VALUES (default, '$trackname', '0', '0')";
    mysqli_query($con, $addquery);
    $i++;
}

?>
```

I got my code to finally import into the database.  Here is the resulting code.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $trackname = basename($file);
    echo $trackname."**";
    $addquery = "INSERT INTO Music (trackname, numlikes, numplays) VALUES ('$trackname', '0', '0')";
    mysqli_query($con, $addquery);

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $addquery);
    If ($result) 
    {
    echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error: " . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Which line in your example is line 23 in your script?

Comment: try debugging it, I advice using XDebug (uses the DBGp protocol for debugging PHP).

Comment: When an array goes out of bounds, it doesn't return null, you receive this notice because you're trying to read an index that does not exist. You can use either `while (isset($files[$i])){` or `while (@$files[$i]) {` (last one not recommended)

Comment: line 23 is that the start of while

Comment: @Dknacht Your solution did remove the warning message!  Had I know it was just a warning, not an error, I wouldn't have made a big deal of it.   Now I have to figure out why my data isn't showing up in the database.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have 39+ files in your folder.
You can replace the `while` with `foreach`

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $trackname = basename($file);
    echo $trackname."**";
    $addquery = "INSERT INTO music (trackname, numlikes, numplays) VALUES ('$trackname', '0', '0')";
    mysqli_query($con, $addquery);
}
```

This way, you will iterate only the files you have and will not throw the notice you have.

If you still want to use `while`, make sure you have a stop point:

```
while ($files[$i]) {
    if(!isset$files[$i]) {
        break;
    }
    ....
```

If the ID is autoincrement column, there is no need to specify the ID column in your insert:

```
INSERT INTO music (trackname, numlikes, numplays) VALUES ('$trackname', '0', '0')
```

Comment: it will stop when $files[$i] is false-ish. when trying to access an index that doesn't exist it will return NULL, and NULL is false-ish, the while won't run forever.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
So does it appear that the code is working, and I should start looking at my database, maybe permission issues?  I've ran the code through online checkers, they always come back okay.

Comment: Works with notice. It's better to fix that. Also, check my version of the insert command, it may works for you. Do you got any error while trying to insert?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, I just tried your code, and it also got rid of the message.  I still don't have any data showing up in the database.

Comment: How would I make a check that the data was successfully written?  Is there PHP code that will verify it's posted successfully?

Comment: You can set the return of your query to a variable `$result = mysqli_query(...)`. If `$result != false`, then it works. What is the return of `mysqli_error($con);` after the insert command?

Comment: Okay, I got the error check to work, and now I've got a new warning.  PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in my/path/enumeratemusic.php on line 36

Comment: what is in line 36?

Comment: lol, it's the start of $result.  Yes I'm new here too I can't get the code to look pretty.  Also, here is the printout on the screen...not all just a few.  Volbeat.mp3**ErrorVolbeat - Healing Subconsciously.mp3**Error

Comment: 'foreach ($files as $file) {
    $trackname = basename($file);
    echo $trackname."**";
    $addquery = "INSERT INTO music (trackname, numlikes, numplays) VALUES (default, '$trackname', '0', '0')";
    mysqli_query($con, $addquery);
    $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO music (default, trackname, numlikes, numplays) VALUES (default, '$trackname', '0', '0')");
    If ($result) 
    {
    echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error";
    }
}
?>'

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
while ($files[$i]) {
```

will print this warning when you get past the end of the `$files` array. If there are 39 files, then `$files[39]` doesn't exist, so trying to access it will report that the index is undefined. The test will then fail, and the loop stops as intended.

Instead of testing the value itself, you should test whether the element exists:

```
while (isset($files[$i])) {
```

or you can use the more normal `foreach` loop, as in Felippe Duarte's answer.